# Node Express - Route path colon parameter exception

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

Currently I have two routes in my app:

`/invoice/:invoice` returns JSON data of an Invoice document from Mongoose

`/invoice/preview` returns a preview of an invoice inside an HTML template (note that this doesn't always preview an existing invoice, it could also be a non-existing of which its data is supplied via url parameters, which is why the route cannot be `/invoice/:invoice/preview`)

**Question**

There should be a better way to declare these two specific routes, because the `/invoice/preview` route now calls both handlers, since it matches both regexes.

If we were talking in CSS selectors `/invoice/:invoice:not(preview)` would be the behavior I want. Unfortunately I don't find any documentation for this.

Is there any way to achieve this or any way to improve this endpoint structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare more specific routes first:

```
router.get('/invoice/preview', ...);

router.get('/invoice/:invoice', ...);
```

Express checks routes in order of declaration, so once it has matched a request against `/invoice/preview` (and provided that its handler sends back a response), the less-specific `/invoice/:invoice` won't be considered.

Alternatively, if `:invoice` should always match a specific pattern (say a MongoDB `ObjectId`), you can limit the route to requests matching that pattern:

```
router.get('/invoice/:invoice([a-fA-F0-9]{24})', ...);
```

That pattern doesn't match *"preview"*, so the order wouldn't matter so much in that case.

If this isn't possible, you could create a middleware that would check if `req.params.invoice` matches *"preview"* and, if so, would pass along the request further down the handler chain:

```
let notIfPreview = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.params.invoice === 'preview') return next('route');
  next();
};

router.get('/invoice/:invoice', notIfPreview, ...);
router.get('/invoice/preview', ...);
```

(documented [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-handlers))

Comment: Your first solution was not ideal as due to project setup the less-specific one will be declared first. However, the solution with the regex works perfectly!

Comment: @KeesvanLierop just for completeness sake, if it wasn't possible to create a pattern for `:invoice`, there's another solution which I added to my answer.